# ASP.NET Core 2 No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization

I want to provide authorization in an ASP.NET Core 2 application. 
After sending the model with the data in Account/Login, after the call to `await Authenticate(user)`, I get an error message.
I can not understand where there is a lack of description.

**Startup.cs**

```
//ConfigureServices
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie("TmiginScheme", options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

//Configure
app.UseAuthentication();
```

**AccountController**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        User user = null;
        Cryptex cryptex = new Cryptex();
        string password = cryptex.EncryptText(model.Password, "TMigin");

        // Ищем user
        user = fStorage.Users.GetUserByLogin(model.Login);
        if (user != null)
        {
            if (string.Compare(user.Password, password) != 0)
            {
                user = null;
            }
        }

        if (user != null)
        {
            await Authenticate(user);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "CMS");
        }

        else
        {
            // Логируем ошибку входа
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Ошибка входа");
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}

private async Task Authenticate(User user)
{
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.Name),
        new Claim("CMS", "True")
    };
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("TmiginScheme", principal);
}
```

**fixed**

Not working, as I placed the code after the `app.UseMvc(...){}`.
In the screenshot the correct location.

[image: correctly]

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem but author's solution didn't work for me. 
I was migrating from .NET Core 1.1 to .NET Core 2.0.

In my case I was using:

```
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(...);
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(...);
```

and i should be using:

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(...);
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(...);
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I've been trying stuff for a solid 8+ hours, and this turned out to be the fix.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the issue is you are configuring the Default Scheme to be `Cookies` when you used `options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;` and than you used different Scheme which is `TmiginScheme` when you used `AddCookie("TmiginScheme"`.

Than in `AccountController` you created new `ClaimsIdentity` without specifying the authentication type and finally you tried to Sign In using scheme name different than what you specified in `options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;`.

To solve your issue change `AddCookie("TmiginScheme"` to `.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`.

Change `var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);` to `var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`.

Finally change `await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("TmiginScheme", principal);` to `await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);`